# RTNETLINK answers: Invalid argument for specific IP Ranges

Tags: route

```
ip route add blackhole 64.79.89.0/19
ip route add blackhole 64.79.85.0/19
```

I try to add these ranges into route but they give

```
RTNETLINK answers: Invalid argument
```

I am not sure if it is about those ranges or a specific problem on my server but other IP ranges work without any issue.

How can I detect the cause of the problem?

Comment: `64.79.89.0` and `64.79.85.0` are `/24` at max. The `/19` that covers them (and more) would be `64.79.64.0/19`.

Comment: @TomYan Thank you, these are XLHOST Ip ranges which are known to be malicious. Those ranges are all over the internet, I am not sure why they were shared wrong like this. You can check they were also shared like /19 in this post too https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29736449/how-to-block-access-by-ip-using-htaccess